# method gets called multiple times in angular material autocomplete

Tags: css, angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular7

We have created a component using **Angular material**'s **autocomplete**. To display the options, we are traversing through an **array of 51 objects**. I am applying a CSS class to the already selected option. The **isAccountingTypeSelected** method determines whether the option was selected or not.
The method gets called **51*28 = 1428 times**. I don't seem to understand the reason? It should only be called **51 times**, shouldn't it?

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <input type="text" matInput #autoCompleteInput [formControl]="autocompleteForm" [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Choose Accounting Type" aria-label="Number">

  <span matSuffix class="close-icon hover" *ngIf="autoCompleteInput.value" (click)="clearAll($event)"></span>
  <span matSuffix class="arrow-drop-down-icon hover" (click)="openPanel()"></span>

  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="accountingTypeSelected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let accountingType of filteredAccountingTypes | async" [value]="accountingType.code">
      <span class="accounting-type-options" [class.selected]="isAccountingTypeSelected(accountingType.code)">
        {{ accountingType.name + ' (' + accountingType.code + ')' }}
      </span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

isAccountingTypeSelected(code: string): boolean {
  console.log('I was called');
  if (this.selectedAccountingTypes.find((accountingType: AccountingType) => accountingType.code === code)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular uses changedetection lifecycle multiple times to check if the function has changed for [class.selected] or ngClass. If you use function, it will call multiple times. For this reason the use of function is not advised when you bind, instead you should calculate the values in your component.ts file and just bind the values to ngClass or [class].

**Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-angular-valuechange)**

N.B: We know when we change selected value it triggers a event change, we can calculate it and attach the calculation result to the [class.my-class] or ngClass.

Comment: please check the stackblitz to get an example like yours

Answer (score 2):

Angular is gonna evaluate that expression every time it checks for changes, which in your case might be the css being added to your span elements.
Calling methods from the template in a for loop is not the best approach because they are called very often. You should instead store the result in a property and bind to this property instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bind problem. Angular checks more times the result value. You can try with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.CheckOnce`

Answer (score 0):

Your ngFor loop needs track a specific id so it won't re-render for nothing. Try this:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let accountingType of filteredAccountingTypes | async; trackBy: trackByCode"[value]="accountingType.code">
</mat-option>
```

Then you add this function:

```
trackByCode(index: number, accountingType: yourType): string {
    return accountingType.code;
}
```